# How can I plot a gridded figure as shown in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, grid, figure

[image]

I would to plot above the above figure with some or none characters in the boxes. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to do this as a plot? Can you use [UITABLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitable.html) instead?

Comment: Agreed. Definitely an application for uitable.

Comment: @b3, consider revising comment into an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want a plot, you can do it with a function like this:

```
function plotGrid(x)

dims = size(x);

% Get grid
tick_x = linspace(0, 1, dims(2)+1);
tick_y = linspace(0, 1, dims(1)+1);

% Get center points
pt_x = (0.5:dims(2)) / dims(2);
pt_y = (0.5:dims(1)) / dims(1);

[pt_x pt_y] = meshgrid(pt_x, pt_y);

% Plot
figure; hold on; axis off
plot([tick_x; tick_x], repmat((0:1)', 1, dims(2)+1), 'k')
plot(repmat((0:1)', 1, dims(1)+1), [tick_y; tick_y], 'k')
text(pt_x(:), pt_y(:), x(:), 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center')
```

For example:

```
>> x = num2cell(randi(10, [10 6]));
>> plotGrid(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One method for displaying tabular data on a figure is to use [UITABLE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitable.html):

```
data = 

    'U1'    'U2'    'U3'    'U4'    'U5' 
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []       []
      []      []      []      []    'U85'

>> uitable('Data', data, 'Units', 'normalized', 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);
```

which produces:

[image]